# Does UA Rush bodywear improve athletic performance?

Tags: physiology, sport

Under Armor is selling a products made from a new fabric called [Rush](https://about.underarmour.com/news/2019/03/ua-rush-2019-scientifically-tested-athlete-proven).

> During performance, the body emits heat. The responsive UA RUSH fabric absorbs that heat and converts it into infrared energy that is re-emitted back into the body. This recycled energy increases temporary localized circulation, promoting improved performance, energy and recovery. When worn, UA RUSH stimulates increased endurance and strength.

I fail to see how giving back infrared energy (assuming it even does) would have any physiological benefit.

Does this product work, as claimed?

Comment: The real question is not whether this special fabric that keeps you warm can enhance performance. The question is whether it does a better job of enhancing performance than any other fabric that keeps you warm (like, say, a cheap cotton sweatshirt).

Comment: " The responsive UA RUSH fabric absorbs that heat and converts it into infrared energy that is re-emitted back into the body" -> This is basically what _everything_ made to make you feel warm does.

Comment: I also find it amusing they made an effort to avoid the word "infrared radiation", which would be the proper scientific term for the effect at play. This alone makes my slap a "technobullshit" sticker to that site.

Comment: One kind of wonders who would want to wear clothing that doesn't keep them cool when they exercise strenuously.  This clothing would appear to only be of benefit for people who do only very brief exercises -- perhaps gymnasts or javelin throwers.

Comment: @T.Sar It's not uncommon for advertisers to avoid anything nuclear/radiation sounding when selling to the public, since "nuclear" tends to have a negative public connotation.  That's why you go to the hospital to get an MRI scan instead of an NMRI scan, as it was originally called.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Warm clothing could certainly be useful for exercising in cold weather (e.g., skiiing). The main problem I have with the marketing language here is that they are presenting the idea of clothing that keeps the body warm as if it's some brilliant new innovation that has never existed before. Warm clothing has existed longer than all of recorded history.

Comment: @JimmyM. -- But why did they gut the CAT and make it CT?

Comment: @DanielRHicks Actually, the "A" appears to have been added to "CT Scan", not the other way around, based on "CT Scan" having approximately 4x as many hits in Google Scholar as "CAT Scan" during the 1970s, when the technology was invented.  "CT" remains the "official" and more commonly used term.

Comment: @JimmyM. - I guess that way they feel they can use carrots instead of cats.

Comment: @T.Sar I like how they lead with it too, so anyone who knows the basics of blackbody radiation can immediately dismiss it as a pointless product.  This is like the worst advertising blurb ever.  "Our fabric reacts approximately the same way as every other fabric when exposed to heat".  Plus, they are totally wasting a step if they actually want to specifically use IR radiation.  Why bother to absorb and re-emit it when you could just line the fabric with something IR reflective and have it "recycle" back to your body without any conversion required!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I started with search engines looking for supporting evidence. However, I found none, so I decided to [contact](https://underarmour.custhelp.com/) Under Armour directly. (Ping me in chat and add a comment for the full transcript. I have saved a copy.)

Here are excerpts from the customer service representative (emphasis added):

> There is [sic] scientific studies proving this technology is affective [sic] and proven although this **has not been posted for the public yet**.
>
> The only information currently posted are [sic] from news articles. [[the one linked in the question](https://about.underarmour.com/news/2019/03/ua-rush-2019-scientifically-tested-athlete-proven)]
>
> I do apologize I **do not have a release date for this information at this time**.
>
> We do **currently have internal documents** and test [sic] on this product.

What this means is that (in Under Armour's own words), internal confidential scientific testing showed the product was effective and operated as advertised. The public does not have access to such scientific testing and, thus, cannot verify Under Armour's claim. A release date for Under Armour's internal scientific documents has not been planned.

> Does this product work, as claimed?

**With publicly available information, the claims cannot be verified.**

Disclaimer: I am not (and never was) affiliated with Under Armour. There is no conflict of interest.

Comment: I immediately requested a supervisor, who was unavailable. This conversation alone took 30 minutes (20 minutes of queueing and 13 min and 28 seconds of talking). I am posting this answer to save other people time and effort in tracking down an answer.

Comment: Also, couldn't find studies relating "infrared" and "circulation."

Comment: Whether a claim can be verified with publicly available information  or whether it's "not even wrong" are two different things.

Comment: FYI, the only part of their statement that really requires questioning is the relationship between infrared heating and "temporary localized circulation", and that the circulation promotes "improved performance, energy and recovery".  The part about converting the heat to infrared itself isn't special at all, and technically every fabric does this to some extent, and they claim no values for how effectively it does so.  (It's the basics of [black-body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) )

Comment: @jmac I suppose the best way to reflect infrared light back to the wearer would be to have an inner black layer and an outer silvery layer. Still not entirely sure why you would want to fight the body's desire to not heat up during workout, though.

Comment: @JohnDvorak They could skip an entire middleman here by just using a reflective interior clothing.  That way, the infrared radiation from your body is bouncing right back to your body, instead of being absorbed and re-emitted by the clothing.  It's not clear what exactly they are trying to accomplish; but this would be a great way to slow-cook yourself.

Comment: @JMac maybe they are trying to low-pass filter your body heat, so that you keep cooking even while resting at a bench after your workout.

Comment: @JohnDvorak "low-pass filter your body heat" Sorry, had to laugh. I have never seen this creative use of "low-pass filter" before. Could you clarify a bit though? +1

Comment: @Christian From [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2005/sep/19/ideas.g2): "'Not even wrong' is enjoying a resurgence as the put-down of choice for questionable science..." The science in the claim is questionable. UA can't even publicly support it with real scientific results! (Instead, they cite "internal documents"....how questionable.)

Comment: @BarryHarrison The linked article said that "not even wrong" refers to whether a claim is falsifiable in the sense Popper used the term. Claims that can invalidated by possible experiments are falsifiable in the sense Popper used the term regardles of whether or not people actually ran experiments or whether documents about those experiments are published.

Comment: @Christian I will remove that sentence for now.

Comment: Next time you could just edit, right?